# Simplified Scrappy won't locate js element

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get data from the webpage https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/price-btc.html and I have the code:

```
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
js = doc.getElementByText('new Dygraph', tag='script').html
js = js[js.find('document.getElementById("container"),') + len('document.getElementById("container"),'):]
js = js[:js.find(', {labels:')] # Get data part
js = js.replace('[new Date("', '').replace('")', '')[1:-2]
data = [kv.split(',') for kv in js.split('],')]
```

which works for other pages on the same website, but on the price page, it returns a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. The code for this page seems to be the same as the rest, so I don't why this one returns an error. For example on https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/transactions-btc.html it works perfectly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong. I don't know why. You can use the following line.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

html = req.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-price.html')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# js = doc.getElementByText('new Dygraph', tag='script').html
js = doc.selects('script').contains('new Dygraph')[0].html  # Change to this
js = js[js.find('document.getElementById("container"),') +
        len('document.getElementById("container"),'):]
js = js[:js.find(', {labels:')]  # Get data part
js = js.replace('[new Date("', '').replace('")', '')[1:-2]
data = [kv.split(',') for kv in js.split('],')]
```